# Google Analytics: Cross Domain Rollup to Single Entity with Single Jquery Link Push

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, cross-domain

The goal is to roll up external domains that are considered part of one site into a single property and entity so that conversions do not show referral mediums or bounces. I want to setup cross domain tracking under a Single Entity and single JS file shared by all sites.

There are three different domains that really are part of one site: www.example.com, exampleblog.com, examplestore.com.

I've read the solution that Google proposes to have different code blocks on the external sites, but I want to create a single file for all sites and link to that on the primary domain. I have created a single JS file that I am hoping to use so that the code is easier to main and I don't have to mess with the external domains. I want to use Jquery to push the _link for the external domains that are not www.example.com. So, if it is not the main domain, then it sets the domain to none and pushes the _link into the cookie.

However, the external domains still show as "referrals" in the medium and display the source of that referral. Instead, we want the source to be direct and the medium to be none.

Here is what displays in analytics:

- www.example.com/page1.html
- Source: (direct)
- Medium: (none)
- exampleblog.com/page2.html
- Source: example.com
- Medium: Referral
- examplestore.com/page3.html
- Source: exampleblog.com
- Medium: Referral
- www.example.com/page4.html
- Source: (direct)
- Medium: (none)

The problem is with the page entries for the examplestore and exampleblog. They show as referrals when they should be forced to display as direct.

Note: I have a filter to show domain in the page name. We have a full profile and a different property setup to show referrals, so this is only for a particular purpose for conversions and goal funnels.

```
// Cross Domain Tracking Under a Single Entity
alert("Loading Google...");

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-3']);


    var locText = document.location + '';
    console.log(window.location.host);

    // one if statement just needs to know if it's at our primary domain
    var exampleDomain = /example\.com/i;

    if(exampleDomain.test(locText)){
        //Roll Up (domain and subdomains)
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']);

    } else {
        //Tag
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
            _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', window.location.host]);

    }

    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



    (function() {

    // load the ga.js file.  This happens last now.
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert("Ready");
    jQuery('a').each(function() {
           var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
            alert(a + " " + this.href);        
           //check if it is external
           if(!a.test(this.href)) {
               alert("external link");

               jQuery(this).click(function(event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   event.stopPropagation();
                   alert("GOOGLED");
                   // Google it
                   _gaq.push(['_link',this.href]); 
                   return false;
               });
           }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use both cross-domain tracking and [_addIgnoredRef()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef) to prevent GA from having the domains show up as referrers.

Definitely test your cross-domain jQuery approach to make sure that the GA __utma cookie is being set correctly after you make the jump.  It sounds like a new session is starting when the user jumps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out tonight and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: All of the alerts trigger as expected. I am wondering, do I need to set gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']); to www.example.com since there is some IIS ISAPI rewriting going on that forces the domain to www. Like this? gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.example.com']);

Comment: The _addIgnoredRef and _setAllowLinker lines have to come before the _trackPageview.  These are properties of the tracker.

Comment: ok, i edited the code above. I moved the addIgnoredRef into the block where I set setDomainName to none. I moved it out of the jquery A click function and just left the _link. Does that all look right? What about the www. part with the Isapi Rewriter?

Comment: I tested your script and it is correctly executing the _link and passing the GA cookies to the external URL.  On that external URL, you will also want to ensure that _setAllowLinker is set to true.  The isapi rewriter should have no impact.

Comment: Thanks, if they share the same JS code, then they should both have the setAllowLinker. I don't have to change anything, do I then?

Comment: Correct; it looks good. You should test it and when the user makes the hop, if you look at your __utma cookie, you should recognize the consistent visitor id within it.